# like_count from link_stats vs widget likes

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I'm using this url to retrieve xml data for a web page:

https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=select%20%20share_count,%20like_count,%20comment_count,%20total_count,%20click_count%20from%20link_stat%20where%20url=%27http://www.justinboots.com/en/Justin_America_Zone.html?item_id=266%27&format=xml

The returned data is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
- <fql_query_response xmlns="http://api.facebook.com/1.0/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" list="true">
- <link_stat>
<like_count>56</like_count> 
</link_stat>
</fql_query_response>
```

or a like_count of 56; however, my facebook widget displays 84 likes.

If I like a page both counts increment by 1.  If I click unlike the both decrease by 1. What's the correlation between like_count and the facebook widgetlikes???

Answer (score 0):

the like plugin / facebook widget counter shows more than the likes it will show the total_count

```
SELECT total_count FROM link_stat WHERE url='http://www.justinboots.com/en/Justin_America_Zone.html?item_id=266'
```

this will return the correct value.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not correct. There is still a difference for e.g. http://www.o2thinkbig.de/projekt/2105 - total_count is 345, while the like button says 418.
There is a bug report about this at: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/169035286562837/